# how to change the remote API path to localhost using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm accessing the API URL which is located remotely[in US] using the browser. It works fine, displays the API link JSON data(valid json data).  When i try to access the same using the AJAX call in the script, it fails with 401 unauthorized error even with valid credentials and key.

I got suggestion to make the path to the API server[remotely located] and configure port number to 81. Can you please suggest me how to configure this.

Script:

```
$.ajax({
    cache:    false,
    type:     "GET",
    async:    true,
    dataType: "JSON",
    username: "myemailid",
    password: "mypassword",
    url:      "http://<remotehostipaddress>:82/JSON/Lookups/ComponentTypes",
    data:     { apiKey: "api key" },
    success:  function(results) { alert("Success!" },
    error:    function(xhr)     { alert("Error!" }
});
```

Comment: You're running into the AJAX same-origin restriction. You need to run a proxy on your own server.

Comment: ...or put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the AJAXed server, if it is under your control.

Comment: No, the remote url is not under my control so i cant change the headers. I tried using jsonp, when running the script after trying with datatype jsonp it displays the contents of the url only in the chrome debugger (preview and response section) not in the browser, it is not entering the success path. Since it has valid json data.

Comment: If the server does not have CORS or JSONP enabled, there's no way to call the API from a cross domain origin ...

Comment: this is probably CORS or JSONP , this is backend problem.